# dplyr summarise by two conditions with filtering

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data not unlike `foo` below. Observations ordered in time with measurements for different groups.

```
library(tidyverse)
n <- 500
r <- 0.001
a <- 5
foo <- data.frame(Time = 1:n) %>%
  mutate(A = a*(1+r)^Time + rnorm(n), B = rnorm(n,mean=a,sd=2)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Time, names_to = "Group", values_to = "Measurement")

foo %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(x=Time,y=Measurement,color=Group)) +
  geom_line()
```

What I want to know is for a given time period (say > 250 in this example), how many measurements are above or below a given quantile value for a group over the entire data set. E.g., the 10th, 50th, and 90th quantiles calculated using the entire data set.

```
fooQuants <- foo %>% group_by(Group) %>%
  reframe(Measurement=quantile(Measurement, probs = c(0.1,0.5,0.9))) %>%
  add_column(Quant = rep(paste0("Q",c(0.1,0.5,0.9)),2))

# eg for group A with Time > 250 this is the number of times that Measurement is above 90th quant
A90th <- fooQuants %>% filter(Group == "A", Quant == "Q0.9") %>% pull(Measurement)
foo %>% filter(Time > 250, Group == "A") %>% summarise(n=sum(Measurement >= A90th))
# eg for group B with Time > 250 this is the number of times that Measurement is above 90th quant
B90th <- fooQuants %>% filter(Group == "B", Quant == "Q0.9") %>% pull(Measurement)
foo %>% filter(Time > 250, Group == "B") %>% summarise(n=sum(Measurement >= B90th))
```

I'd like to do this for all groups in `foo` and all the different quantile levels in `fooQuants`. E.g.,

```
#foo %>% filter(Time > 250) %>% select(Group,Measurement) %>%
#  group_by(Group) %>%
#  summarise(`the number of instances where the measurement is gt or lt each quantile in fooQuants`)
```

Tips appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr) # v1.1.0+ for "join_by"
foo %>%
  left_join(fooQuants, join_by(Group, closest(Measurement >= Measurement))) %>% 
  mutate(Quant = coalesce(Quant, "Q0")) %>%
  filter(Time > 250) %>%
  count(Group, Quant) %>%
  mutate(share = n / sum(n), .by = Group)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 8 × 4
  Group Quant     n share
  <chr> <chr> <int> <dbl>
1 A     Q0        4 0.016
2 A     Q0.1     65 0.26 
3 A     Q0.5    131 0.524
4 A     Q0.9     50 0.2  
5 B     Q0       28 0.112
6 B     Q0.1     92 0.368
7 B     Q0.5    105 0.42 
8 B     Q0.9     25 0.1
```

Comment: Holy moly! That is some serious wrangling skill. I think I follow -- the idea of the `left_join` and the  `join_by` was the logical leap I was missing. Thanks.